# Is there any guarantee to be sure the left side of && operator is always evaluated first?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

As the title says: Is there any guarantee from C++ Standard to be sure the left side of `&&` (or `and`) operator always evaluated first? To be honest, I couldn't search in [C++17 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf), I don't know which section I most look for.

### Sample of Problem:

I want to do something like this:

```cpp
std::unordered_map<std::size_t, std::weak_ptr<T>> objects;

bool f (std::size_t const id) {
  bool result = false;

  if (not objects.at(id).expired()) {
    auto const& object = objects.at(id).lock();

    /* Here left side of `and` most be evaluated first */
    result = object->parent->remove(id) and 
             objects.erase(id) == 1;
  }

  return result;
}
```

And want to be sure there is no problem with the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **[expr.log.and]/1** ... Unlike `&`, `&&` guarantees left-to-right
> evaluation: the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand is false.

Comment: With the caveat that a user-defined `operator&&` does not have this short-circuit behavior.  And a recommendation to avoid making one's own user-defined `operator&&`.